# Should "pro se" be a tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Should "pro se" be added to the list of tags?

Example question where I would like to apply such a tag: [Alternative to "Isn't it true that...?" when questioning witnesses](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13173/alternative-to-isnt-it-true-that-when-questioning-witnesses/13359#13359)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be used only for questions *about* *pro se* representation, and not for questions that happen to have arisen *during* *pro se* representation.

Two reasons. First, [we shouldn't use meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Second, that an issue happens to have arisen during *pro se* representation doesn't change the legal answer, especially since we don't provide legal advice.

Comment: I'm not asking for specific legal advice.  I'm asking about legal procedures in general terms.

Comment: @aparente001 Then the fact that they arose in the *pro se* setting is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, and it has been here for a while: [pro-se](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-se).

Comment: Usually, when you type the first few letters of an existing tag, the existing tags that contain that string appear in a list.  But that doesn't work for this tag when you type *pro*.

Comment: @aparente001 - It does appear ... if you have enough room.  The problem is that it's currently ranked 9th on the list of tags with words beginning with "pro."  I can't think of a way to resolve that.

Comment: That is interesting.  I tried typing in "en" (thinking I would get a lot of things having to do with England and things English), and I got exactly six items.  There are a lot because many words have "en somewhere in the middle of the word.  Then I tried "pro" again, and got six suggestions again.  I wonder if the software allows for increasing this number?

Comment: @aparente001 - If you're typing in the tag while composing or editing a question it appears the autocomplete only shows the top six.  You can get a longer list [on the tags page](http://law.stackexchange.com/tags).

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is yes.  I have been learning about pursuing a legal matter *pro se*, and I think it would be useful for me, and for other pro se individuals, to be able to pull up other relevant Q&As.